# Remove all the namespaces from under the root node

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, serialization, namespaces

I am using System.Xml.Serialization to serialize a class into an xdocument.

```
<tns:RatingRequest xmlns:tns="http://somewebsite/services/rating" 
xmlns:tns1="http://somewebsite/services/rating" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://somewebsite/services/rating.xsd ">
   <tns:Configuration>
      <tns:Client>
         <tns:TradingPartnerNum>101010</tns:TradingPartnerNum>
      </tns:Client>
   </tns:Configuration>
   <tns:PickupDate>2017-12-12T00:00:00</tns:PickupDate>
   <tns:LatestDeliveryDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</tns:LatestDeliveryDate>
   <tns:Stops>
      <tns:Index>1</tns:Index>
   </tns:Stops>
</tns:RatingRequest>
```

What I need is only the first node having the tns: namespace like

```
<tns:RatingRequest xmlns:tns="http://somewebsite/services/rating" 
xmlns:tns1="http://somewebsite/services/rating" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://somewebsite/services/rating.xsd ">
   <Configuration>
      <TradingPartner>
        <TradingPartnerNum>101010</TradingPartnerNum>
      </TradingPartner>
   </Configuration>
   <PickupDate>2017-10-27T00:00:00-05:00</PickupDate>
   <DeliveryDate>-05:00</DeliveryDate>
   <Stops>
     <Stop>
       <Index>1</Index>
     </stop>
   </stops>
</tns:RatingRequest>
```

Is there a clean way of doing this?

Comment: The two xml fragments describe different data - the namespace of the child elements is different. If you want the bottom one: *tell it to use the root namespace*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick here is that in the xml you want, the namespace of the child elements is the empty namespace. Your *root* element is in the `"http://somewebsite/services/rating"`, and by default the namespace is *inherited*; so: you need to include `Namespace = ""` on whatever xml serializer attributes you are using for the child elements. For example, if you have:

```
[XmlElement("PickupDate")]
public DateTime SomeDate {get;set;}
```

then it might become:

```
[XmlElement("PickupDate", Namespace = "")]
public DateTime SomeDate {get;set;}
```

You will need to repeat that for the other elements.

Comment: That is perfect and so simple. Thank You!